# Writing a function which has bisect_left as part of it to accept iteration inputs

Tags: python, function, matplotlib, iteration, range

I have written a function in python as follows:

```
from bisect import basect_left
    def find(i):
        a=[1,2,3]
        return bisect_left(a,i);
```

I want this function to accept iterations as input and generate iterations as output. Especially I am working with numpy and I want to be able to use linspace as input and
get the output for this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
t=scipy.linspace(0,10,100)
plt.plot(t,find(t))
```

UPDATE!!!:
I realized the error I get is:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Which is given for `bisect_left` from `bisect` library. How can I solve this problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your code actually works as it is, however I give some comments:

```
def sqr(i):
  return i*i;                      # you don't need the ";" here 

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy                       # you should use "import numpy as np" here
t=scipy.linspace(0,10,100)         # this would be "np.linspace(...)" than
plt.plot(t,sqr(t))
```

[image: simple_figure.png]

With your call `scipy.linspace(0,10,100)` you are creating a numpy array (scipy imports linspace from numpy), which has built in support for vectorized calculations.
Numpy provides vectorized [`ufuncs`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html#available-ufuncs) which you can use together with [indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#indexing) if you need  more complicated calculations. Matplolib accepts numpy arrays as input and plots the values in the array.

Here is an example using [`ipython`](http://ipython.org/) as an interactive console:

```
In [27]: ar = np.arange(10)

In [28]: ar
Out[28]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [29]: ar * ar
Out[29]: array([ 0,  1,  4,  9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81])

In [30]: np.sin(ar)
Out[30]: 
array([ 0.        ,  0.84147098,  0.90929743,  0.14112001, -0.7568025 ,
       -0.95892427, -0.2794155 ,  0.6569866 ,  0.98935825,  0.41211849])
In [31]: ar.mean()
Out[31]: 4.5

In [32]: ar[ar > 5] 
Out[32]: array([6, 7, 8, 9])

In [33]: ar[(ar > 2) & (ar < 8)].min()
Out[33]: 3
```

Comment: Actually in my real code I used np. Here when I was giving example I forgot it, but thank you very much. But still it doesn't work and this is the error I get:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: OH! I just realized why gives that error and that is because of bisec_left in my code!

Comment: I edited my question according to new information but thanks again

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do from your question. Are your sure that your example is correct?. The numpy alternative to bisect should be [`numpy.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use generator expression `plt.plot(t, (sqr(x) for x in t))`
**EDIT:** You can put in in function as well:

```
def sqr(t):
    return (i*i for i in t);
```

Or you can write a [Generator](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) with yield statement:

```
def sqr(t):
   for i in t:
      yield i*i
```

Comment: Thank you, but I still want the way that python functions are written to implement it as part of the function not to do it in the plot

Comment: -1 as the OP genrates a numpy array with `scipy.linspace`, so you don't need any iteration or generator expressions, but you can instead use the built in features.